# DataContractJsonSerializer throws general serialization exception

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to catch/differentiate different serializationExceptions?

For invalid attribute values or invalid json format DataContractJsonSerializer throws serialization exception only.

Comment: your basically using the serialization as a tool to validate the schema.
Try using JsonSchema from Json.Net or similar product.

Comment: @VeNoMiS: Thank you.Is there anyway to do it with the existing classes rather than using any nuget package or tool.

Comment: None if i recall correcly